# Implementing hadoop example, jar error produced

Tags: hadoop

I wanted to execute a hadoop example and it says jar not found. The code was run using `hadoop jar hadoop-examples-*.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+`

The error produced was:

> Not a valid JAR : /home/rahul/hadoop/hadoop-examples-*.jar

Comment: You will need to show  more information. Please post the relevant code for the community review.

Comment: The command is not able to expand the * character and hence saying not a valid jar. Write the complete jar name

Comment: hey so i put the complete jar code and it still shows the same error... 
the code i put was "hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.3.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+' " ...........
the error shown is 

Not a valid JAR /home/rahul/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.3.jar 

I checked the path to the mapreduce-examples-2.7.3.jar and everything related is perfect.

Please Help as this is just the installation phase and i am stuck since 2 days.

Comment: Also, does this mean that my hadoop installation is complete and the error is related to a problem in my input file ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check the jar specified path ,i think it is the cause of the issue

Comment: This shouldn't be an answer but a comment instead.

Comment: @mrun ok next time, anyways I hope that's will help someone